# Reactjs Counting two element duplicates in object array and storing them with count as object

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I want to display the name, section of user together with the count on how many times they borrowed.

I am struggling to sort them out into object.

models/return.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const returnSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    bookId: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Book'
    }],
    course: {
        type: String,
    },
    returnedDate: {
        type: Date,
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Return', returnSchema);
```

models/user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter your name'],
    },
    course: {
        type: String,
    },
    section: {
        type: String,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter your email'],
        unique: true,
        validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please enter valid email address']
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter your password'],
        select: false
    },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpire: Date
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

my array data that come from my query

```
    const borrowerRanking = await Return.find({}).populate({
            path: 'userId',
            select: 'name course -_id'
        }).select('name course -_id')
```

which has a result of

```
[
  { userId: {name: 'user1', course: 'BSIT'} },
  { userId: {name: 'user1', course: 'BSIT'} },
  { userId: {name: 'user1', course: 'BSIT'} },
  { userId: {name: 'user1', course: 'BSIT'} },
  { userId: {name: 'user3', course: 'BTIT'} },
  { userId: {name: 'user3', course: 'BTIT'} },
  { userId: {name: 'user1', course: 'BSIT'} }
]
```

and retching only the name and course by:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < borrowerRanking.length; i++) {
        borrowerArr.push({
            name: borrowerRanking[i].userId.name,
            course: borrowerRanking[i].userId.course,
        })
    }
```

which show this result:

```
[
  {name: 'user1', course: 'BSIT'},
  {name: 'user1', course: 'BSIT'},
  {name: 'user1', course: 'BSIT'},
  {name: 'user1', course: 'BSIT'},
  {name: 'user3', course: 'BTIT'},
  {name: 'user3', course: 'BTIT'},
  {name: 'user2', course: 'BSIT'}
]
```

and I want to create a new array that a data result like this:

```
[
  {name: 'user1', course: 'BSIT', count:'3'},
  {name: 'user2', course: 'BSIT', count:'2'},
  {name: 'user3', course: 'BTIT', count:'2'}
]
```

Comment: its from a query result which I have filtered from the MongoDB

Comment: sorry, I'm new to stack overflow so i do not know how to format my comment properly

Comment: oh sorry, yeah i have just edited it. thank you for teaching me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It maybe easier (and potentially more efficient) if you perform the logic in MongoDB aggregation.

```js
db.return.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "user",
      "localField": "userId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            name: 1,
            course: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "userId"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$userId"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$userId",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$_id.name",
      course: "$_id.course",
      count: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z6NowfBBLmv)

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems that I posted some missing code that I think mislead you. I apologize for that. i am currently updating my post.

Comment: i think what hindering my code to get the result i am expecting because the variable `borrowerRanking` is giving me an array instead of a db.collection. i tried modifying the code into `const borrowerRanking = await Return.aggregate([...` which gives me the correct counts but name and course it missing due to the userId is a reference to another mongodb collection which is `users` collection

Comment: @sheynn updated the answer. Basically it is just doing the populate with `$lookup`

Comment: Thank you so much @ray, I am now able to fetch the data that I need. This code works for me.

Comment: hi i just want to ask, what should i include in the aggregate function if i want to show `returnedDate` from the returns collection

Comment: @sheynn you mean something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7vH9umbd1pU)?

Comment: I'm now able to fetch `returnedDate` , thanks again @ray